# Is it possible to get photo spheres in Google map bounds

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, photosphere

Is there any way to fetch available photo spheres (within map bounds) using the Google Maps API?

I am trying to build a map like the one [here](https://www.google.com/maps/views/explore?gl=za&ll=51.509195,-0.115447&bd=51.489078,-0.165444,51.529303,-0.065451&z=14&pk=2&pv=2), but can't figure out where to get the photo sphere data from, or if it's even possible - cannot find anything in the documentation other than standard streetview stuff.

edit: I do know that individual photo spheres can be fetched by their `pano_id`, but need a more efficient way to get a bunch of them onto my map. Manually creating a `pano_id` collection isn't an option.

Comment: Seems you can get it by pano id. Not sure there is a way to get all available photoshperes from your map bounds.